# Google Sheets If Function Not running when true

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted to add a button to a report in google sheets. The button works but you can not use it on a phone so I'm told you must use `onEdit`. The problem I'm having is to only make changes when the certain box is edited, but when it is the correct box it seems google freezes and doesn't run the script.

I've already tried with my if as  `(row = 8)` , `(Row == 8)` and `(Row == "8")`.

```
    function onEdit(evt) {
      var range = evt.range;
      var row =  range.getRow().toString();
      Logger.log("line 1");
      Logger.log("edited!! Row: " + row + " and column: " + range.getColumn ());
  
      if (row == "8"){             // && range.getColumn() = 6 ){ (This bit is for after I figure the row issue out.
        Logger.Log("right");
      } else {// esstsgs
        Logger.log("Wasnt the right cell"); 
      }
      Logger.log("Done the thing");
    }
```

So with that code, if I edit any row but 8 my log looks like:

> line 1 edited!!
>
> Row x and Column x
>
> done the thing

But if it is row 8 my log says:

> line 1
>
> Edited!! Row x and Column x

And nothing more, when is it freezing in the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know what you would really like to do with this and I'll set it up for you.  For now hopefully this will help you to figure the logic.

I don't use Logger.log() for debugging this kind of code.  Instead I use the `e.source.toast()` function.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet189')return;//this is important so that you don't get edits from unwanted pages
  //e.source.toast('Flag1');
  if(e.range.rowStart==8 && e.range.columnStart==6) {             
    var msg=Utilities.formatString('You are editing %s.',sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).getA1Notation());
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);
  } 
  if(e.range.rowStart!=8 || e.range.columnStart!=6) {
    var msg=Utilities.formatString('You are not editing F8. Instead you are editing %s.',sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).getA1Notation());
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);
  }
}
```

> You will probably want to change the sheet number before running this.  I didn't set up the Logger.log because I don't like to use it for this kind of code. I did test this and it works fine.

Comment: Tried your code, but couldnt see where the message was meant to be displayed. I use logger.log just for debugging, have a large chunk of cde to replace it once it works the way i think it should.

Comment: It's being displayed on an alert dialog on top of the spreadsheet.  I assume you realize that you can't run this from the code editor.  Just set it up by changing the page name and go to that page and edit some appropriate cells and an alert window will let you know whether it is F8 or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out some mistakes in your code first of all.

- You don't need to make the Row variable a string. `var row =  range.getRow();` is just fine.
- You are always Logging "Line 1", why not update it to actually say which line was updated? `Logger.log("line " + row);`
- Your code will output "Done the thing" regardless of what it did. Maybe just say it did anything when it's the right box?

Your fixed code would look like:

```
function onEdit(evt) {
      var range = evt.range;
      var row =  range.getRow();
      var col =  range.getColumn();

      Logger.log("line " + row + "edited!! Row: " + row + " and column: " + col);

      if (row == 8 && col == 6 ) {
        Logger.log("Right cell. Did the thing.");
        //Call here whatever you want to trigger when this cell changes.
      } //Don't need a "else" if you are not going process anything
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So first of all for your points:1. I know it dosnt need t be a string, just trying to see if it would help, 2. the logging is not what im trying to do, just a way to see how far into the code it made it. (3 is same as 2). So I added your code into my function and it came out with the same result. only logging "line x edited! Row: x and coloum: x" when it was row 8 and coloum 6 it still did not print "Right cell, did the thing".

Comment: @Joost, are you sure you are editing the right cell? Column 6 and Row 8 means cell F8. For ranges, the indexes start at 1.

Comment: Yes, id removed the column requiremnt for testing, anything in row 8 should trigger it. When any other cell is changed the final line of done the thing comes up, when row 8 is edited only what is befor the if comes up. Almost seems like a bigger issue in the google scrits to me.

Comment: @Joost what do you mean "When any other cell is changed"? Can you tell me what appears on the logs when you edit a cell in row 8? I am unable to reproduce the problems you are facing.

Comment: [19-10-31 05:28:30:137 PDT] line 1
[19-10-31 05:28:30:138 PDT] edited!! Row: 8 and collum: 7
This comes up when i edit row 8. It should also include the line that is located within the if, as well as the line that says the thing is done. Its really weird you cant reproduce my results.

Comment: @Joost, this seems to be an issue only you are facing, could you reach out to the [support team](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) and ask for help?